# Return Multiple CheckBox Values if Checked in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple checkbox in my page. i want to retrieve its values if checked.

Here is HTML Code..

```
<input name="ctl1189" type="checkbox" id="chkTicket_189310" class=" chkTicket" value="189310">

<input name="ctl1190" type="checkbox" id="chkTicket_189311" class=" chkTicket" value="189311">
```

And So on..

Javascript Code:

```
function updateTicketAction() {
    var allUpdatedVendorTickets = $('.chkTicket').filter(function() { return this.value != $input.is(':unchecked'); });
    var sFinalUpdateList = '';

    allUpdatedVendorTickets.each(function() {
        var ids = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];

        sFinalUpdateList += ((sFinalUpdateList == '') ? '' : '|') + ids + ',' + $(this).val();
    });
    alert(sFinalUpdateList);
}
```

Comment: No idea what your filter function is supposed to do. `$input` isn't declared in your snippet.

Comment: filter is inbuilt in jquery plugin...$input is tag type

Comment: I know man, I meant you're comparing a `value` property with a boolean. And `$input` is not declared on your code above.

Comment: Why do you use string? It had better use array. Then you can call `join` method, somthing like `finalUpdatelist.join('|')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/feklee/xGHkN). Look in the JavaScript console for the resulting object, which you can then further process.

Code:

```
var checkedCheckboxes = $('.chkTicket:checked'),
    results = {};

checkedCheckboxes.each(function () {
    var key = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    results[key] = $(this).val();
});

function alertResults(results) {
    var text = '', sep = '';
    $.each(results, function (key, value) {
        text += sep + key + '=' + value;
        sep = '|';
    });
    alert(text);
}

alertResults(results);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: It Prints alert as [Object object]

Comment: In Chrome, it prints an object in the development console. You can click a little arrow next to it, to show its contents.

Comment: Try again. Now you get the results in a popup.

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateTicketAction() {
    var sFinalUpdateList = '';
    $("input.chkTicket:checked").each( 
        function() { 
           var ids = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
           var id = ids[1];
           sFinalUpdateList += ((sFinalUpdateList == '') ? '' : '|') + id + ',' + $(this).val();
        } 
    );
    alert(sFinalUpdateList);
}
```

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html

Comment: I edited it, and I added .chkTicket class to the jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var collect='';
$('input:checked').each(function(i,e){  
    collect+=(collect===''? $(e).attr('name')+'='+$(e).val():','+$(e).attr('name')+'='+$(e).val());
    alert(collect);
})
```

Comment: It worked...But it gives undefined values also for unchecked checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/G72S2/) that returns all checked inputs..
One question though, why do you split your id-attribute when you have your id stored in value-attribute? Anyways, hope this works for you!

```
function updateTicketAction() {
  var allUpdatedVendorTickets = $('.chkTicket:checked');
  var sFinalUpdateList = '';

  allUpdatedVendorTickets.each(function () {
    sFinalUpdateList += ((sFinalUpdateList == '') ? '' : '|') + $(this).val();
  }); 

  alert(sFinalUpdateList);
}
```

Comment: I just want to retrieve the Values...as the ID itself have value so doing split thing

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use map():

```
var el = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(i,e){

        var id = $(e).attr('id').replace('chkTicket_', '');
        var val = $(e).val();

        return {
                'id' : id,
                'value' : val
               }

    });

console.log(el[0].id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your filter function is wrong.

```
this.value != $input.is(':unchecked');
```

You're comparing a `.value` property (string) to the return value of the [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) jQuery method (boolean). It's similar to:

```
'value' != !true  //checked
'value' != !false //unchecked
```

Both will always return `true` - unless `value` is `0` or an empty string which evaluates to a falsy value and the right side of the expression evaluates to `false`, for which the `!=` different operator will return `false`.

So, your `filter`'s callback doesn't filter anything at all, except taking out `checked` boxes with value `0` or no value (which is unintentional).

You can avoid using a `filter` function by using the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector:

```
var allUpdatedVendorTickets = $('.chkTicket:checked');
```

Now you'll have a jQuery object containing only the checked `.chkTicket`, much better.

---

Next thing, you're making bad use of strings.

```
"189310,189310|189311,189311"
```

That's what your function is generating. Every time you need to manipulate those results, you'll have to split the string at `|`, creating a new array. It's much better to store it as an array already.

```
var sFinalUpdateList = [];
```

Assuming your keys and values are always the same as in your example, you should store them only once as well.

```
allUpdatedVendorTickets.each(function() {
    sFinalUpdateList.push(this.value);
});
```

This will generate a much more clean and maintainable array with only the checked boxes' values:

```
sFinalUpdateList =>
       [0] -> "189310"
       [1] -> "189311"
```

You can obtain their IDs by appending `chkTicket_` to those values.

### [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/gbbQM/1/)

Comment: @SagarDumbre Yes, consider using arrays or objects (as in feklee's answer) when handling that kind of stuff, it'll save you a lot of headaches in the future. `=]`